# How to call API when offline in android?

Tags: android, api, synchronization

I am successful in calling an API when internet connection is available,
How do i call the same API when there is no internet connectivity?

Basically,
I want to know online and offline syncing?
Where user can add data but it will be pushed to server only if internet is available.
How do i do it?

Comment: Your question is quite broad, and answering it would require describing how to do many things and/or designing a substantially sized program. While there's likely a way to do all of that, you're more likely to get an answer if you describe what you've done so far, and which specific part you're having trouble with. Show your code, and describe the exact behavior you want, as well as how that behavior differs from what happens with your current code. Include the text of any errors. The more detail you give, the more answers you're likely to get. Take a look at the [FAQ] and [ask] for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consume REST Service, you can read [this article about how to use manage offline with Retrofit](https://medium.com/major-league/need-to-make-your-app-work-offline-without-extra-work-retrofit2-to-the-rescue-22714c358791). It's talk about client implemented using Retrofit. If you use Volley, you can use the article to see to implement a cache system based on OkHttp, which is used from Volley too.

I report here a part of the code. Read the article to have the entire code and adapt it to your need.

```
// Add all interceptors you want (headers, URL, logging, stetho logs)
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(provideOfflineCacheInterceptor())
  .addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor())
  .cache(provideCache());

...

private Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() {
        return chain -> {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if (!isConnected()) {
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxStale(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .build();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .removeHeader(HEADER_PRAGMA)
                        .removeHeader(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL)
                        .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                        .build();
            }

            return chain.proceed(request);
        };
    }
```

Comment: This wont help my API when offline

Comment: Are you using Retrofit?

Comment: I am using okhttp and volley